# Keep N first elements from a string fileds using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I try to keep only the 2 first web site in my column **SITE**

Here is my data frame :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 
                   'SITE':['https://www.web01.com ; https://www.web02.com ; https://www.web03.com',
                          
                          'https://www.web01.com ; https://www.web02.com ; https://www.web03.com']})
```

How to do this with Python?

Comment: If any of the answer solved your problem then you can try considering accepting that answer....thnx **:)**

Comment: @AnuragDabas yes :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try via `str.split()` and `str.join()`:

```
df['SITE']=df['SITE'].str.split(' ; ').str[:2].str.join(' ; ')
```

output of `df`:

```
    SITE
0   https://www.web01.com ; https://www.web02.com
1   https://www.web01.com ; https://www.web02.com
```

**OR**(if you want to join by `','`) **:**

```
df['SITE']=df['SITE'].str.split(' ; ').str[:2].str.join(',')
```

output of `df`:

```
    SITE
0   https://www.web01.com,https://www.web02.com
1   https://www.web01.com,https://www.web02.com
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `str.split()` function and take first two elements:

```
df['SITE'] = df['SITE'].str.split(' ; ').str[:2]
```

Output:

```
                                              SITE
0   [https://www.web01.com, https://www.web02.com]
1   [https://www.web01.com, https://www.web02.com]
```

Answer (score 0):

One way:

```
>>> df['SITE'].str.split(';').str[:2].explode().str.strip()
0    https://www.web01.com
0    https://www.web02.com
1    https://www.web01.com
1    https://www.web02.com
Name: SITE, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

Define a function like this:

```
def my_function(text):
    text = text.split(';')
    return ';'.join(text[:2]).strip()
```

Then, apply the function to the target column (SITE):

```
df['SITE'] = df['SITE'].apply(my_function)
```

If you print `df`, it will be like this:

```
  SITE
0 https://www.web01.com ; https://www.web02.com
1 https://www.web01.com ; https://www.web02.com
```

Answer (score 0):

### Sample DataFrame:

```
>>> df
                                                                    SITE
0  https://www.web01.com ; https://www.web02.com ; https://www.web03.com
1  https://www.web01.com ; https://www.web02.com ; https://www.web03.com
```

### Solution 1:

Using `str.rsplit` and slice indexing all the column except the last one.

```
>>> df['SITE'].str.rsplit(';').str[:-1]
0    [https://www.web01.com ,  https://www.web02.com ]
1    [https://www.web01.com ,  https://www.web02.com ]
Name: SITE, dtype: object
```

### Solution 2:

Using `str.extract` with the `regex` method.

```
>>> df['SITE'] = df['SITE'].str.extract(r'(^[https:]+[\/]+\w+\.\w+\.\w+\s\;\s+[https:]+[\/]+\w+\.\w+\.\w+)')
>>> df
                                            SITE
0  https://www.web01.com ; https://www.web02.com
1  https://www.web01.com ; https://www.web02.com
```

It may Further be tuned to shorted version with regex for you given case, like below.

```
>>> df['SITE'] = df['SITE'].str.extract(r'(^[https].*2.com)')
>>> print(df)
                                            SITE
0  https://www.web01.com ; https://www.web02.com
1  https://www.web01.com ; https://www.web02.com
```